# Find page no., line no., and x/y coordinates of selected text in a pdf using java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to find the page no, line no and starting column/ ending column of the selected text in a PDF using Java. So is there any API using which i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

The JPedal PDF library has an example to do this at http://www.jpedal.org/support_egFTIR.php